# Validate OS X username/password in sandboxed application

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to test, *programatically*, whether a given username/password combination is a valid OS X login.

Before sandboxing, I did this with AuthorizationCreate(), but "the authorization services API is not supported within an app sandbox" (Apple docs).

Does anyone know of a sandbox-friendly alternative? It only needs to work for the user account of the current process, if that makes a difference.

Use case: this is a remote access app that requires the Mac username and password in order to connect. (Credentials are received over https.) Obviously I could have the user create an app-specific password, but I was hoping to avoid a YAPP (Yet Another Password Problem).

Comment: As you say and the Apple docs confirm, the authorization services API is not supported with sandboxing and with that I mind, I believe that what you're asking is not possible at present and would require Apple to provide a specific entitlement. I'd be very interested if anyone knows differently.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is supported and I don't see this happening anytime soon. The very idea will break Sandbox purpose.

A thought about why it is not supported? Your App will provide a method of verifying passwords for OS X and if you design your App wrong you might provide an easy way to brute force the OS X password.

Use an App specific password and implement KeyChain support.